# How are multiple ajax requests in a single page processed? Single socket per page or separate socket for request - be it ajax(XHR) or regular http

Tags: javascript, ajax, sockets, http, xmlhttprequest

Given http is stateless, I want to understand it's implications on requests made by clients to server.
Normally a httprequest will result in to a binding between server and client through a socket, which as per my understanding is only valid for a single request and response ( Correct me if wrong: I think a bi-directional socket is created when a client makes "httpRequest". The server uses same socket to send the "httpResponse" and then the server also closes this socket. So the client can no longer use it).
But the way modern web has evolved, what was handled in legacy model though a single request is now handle through several modular AJAX or XHR request (of course am not 100% correct, but most of the web2 or e-com companies do it like this, at least what I have seen.
Ex: http request to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions analysed by chrome dev tools --> network tab (disable cache selected)--> shows in summary 9/38 request | 970 B / 327 KB transfered | Finish: 35.78s ....).

**Question is: Does every AJAX or XHR request (even though originating from the same page or common request) result in a separate socket connection or http has a smart way to handle this by identifying XHR of same page and route them through the same socket.**

Incase if the default is, **separate socket for every XHR**. Is it possible with little more code or configuration to use the same socket for all the XHR's (or the server will simply close the connection after first response no matter what). Or that's were WebSockets come in picture.

**And are there any tools that can show the sockets used along with client ip:port and server ip:port. Firebug or Chrome Dev tools does not seem to show the client ports or sockets involved**

Comment: Have you used your developer tools to see what happens? Open up the 'network' tab, refresh the page, and you'll be able to see visually what's happening.

Comment: @Jacksonkr, i really appreciate your answer. And I expect this info to be present on a debugger. I tried chrome developer --> Network tab, but there is no info about source-ip:port and destination-ip:port  . Am i missing some thing. does firebug caputure this info